# What interface type is suited for implementing strategy with different signature?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, interface

consider the following game code:

```cs
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
    public void UseItem(Item item) {
        item.Use(this);
    }
    public void GetDrunk() {}
}

public class Item {
    public WhatInterface[] itemUsages;

    public void Use(Player player) {
        foreach(var usage in itemUsages) {
            usage.Execute(new ItemUsageArgs {itemUser = player, itemUsed = this})
        }
    }
}

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public Player mainCharacter;
    public Item beer = new Item {itemUsages = new [] {
        new TestConsole(),
        new DamageFromItem (),
        new DrunkFromITem ()
    }}

    private void Start() {
        mainCharacter.Use(beer);
    }
}

public class TestConsole : WhatInterface {
    public void Execute(BaseArgs args) {
        Debug.Log("function call executed");
    }
}

public class DamageFromItem : WhatInterface {
    public void Execute(ItemUsageArgs args) {
        Debug.Log(args.itemUser + " take damage from " + args.itemUsed);
    }
}

public class DrunkFromITem : WhatInterface {
    public void Execute(ItemUsageArgs args) {
        args.itemUser.GetDrunk();
    }
}

public class BaseArgs {}

public class ItemUsageArgs : BaseArgs {
   public Player itemUser;
   public Item itemUsed;
}
```

so how to create interface type code that is suited for itemUsages?

Or do I wrongly create the design for this context?

Basically I'm trying strategy pattern so that item usages could be vary for every kind of item.

Things I tried, creating IItemUsage interface:

```
public interface IItemUsage {
    void Execute(ItemUsageArgs args);
    // but then anything that needs to implement this interface must use this method, even though it only needs BaseArgs.
    // TestConsole class must conform to Execute(ItemUsageArgs) signature..
}

public class TestConsole : IItemUsage {
    public void Execute(BaseArgs args) {
        Debug.Log("function call executed");
    }
    // this won't compile
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for suitable name of your interface?

Comment: I'm asking for the interface type to hold all different usages

Comment: You can create on interface with Execute method. And implement that interface in TestConsole, DamageFromItem and DrunkFromITem classes.

Comment: TestConsole, and other FromItem class has different signature sir, can you provide example code?

Comment: I'm not quite sure about a solution but at least, I'd say your relation Player/Item is two ways and I would avoid that. Most likely the Item has no reason to know about the consumer (Player), item is providing data and Player will use them. You'd think Vodka does not need to know whether a human or a dog drinks it? Same here.

Comment: First you should also fix all the other small errors in your code! Some examples: after `item.Use(this)` there is a `;` missing. After `public void GetDrunk() {}` there is a `;` too much. There is either a type or `var` missing in `foreach(usage in itemUsages)` .. etc. Then you can simply use a generic interface

Comment: @Everts I think it's strategy pattern, otherwise I had to check the item used by player with a lot of ifs. If he use beer then, else if he use potion then, else if he use vodka then, else if he use sword then..

Comment: @derHugo yes sorry, my brain hurt so much when writing the example code, sorry I fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is all of your code, you can make `IItemUsage` generic, and [contravairant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance#generic-interfaces-with-contravariant-generic-type-parameters) on the generic parameter.

```
public interface IItemUsage<in T> where T: BaseArgs {
    void Execute(T args);
}
```

Have `TestConsole` implement `IItemUsage<BaseArgs>` and the other two classes implement `IItemUsage<ItemUsageArgs>`.

Now you can put instances of all three classes into an `IItemUsage<ItemUsageArgs>[]`:

```
IItemUsage<ItemUsageArgs>[] arr = new IItemUsage<ItemUsageArgs>[] { 
    new TestConsole(), new DamageFromItem(), new DrunkFromITem()
};
```

Comment: Probably helpful links: [c# generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics), [`where` (generic type constraint)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint)

Comment: this one is correct, though I don't know why removing the where T on the code still works

Comment: @KevinTanudjaja That is expected. Read the second link posted by derHugo for more info. The `where` clause is to prevent you from accidentally putting a class that is not a subclass of `BaseArgs` into the `<>`s.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement interface with some method, which has input arguments, that can be different types, you must define base argument class or use interface parameter instead.

For example:

```
public interface IItemUsage
{
    void Execute(IItemUsageArgs args);
}
public interface IItemUsageArgs
{
    //place public part of all ItemUsageArgs
}

public class ItemUsageArgs1 : IItemUsageArgs
{

}

public class ItemUsageArgs2 : IItemUsageArgs
{

}
public class ItemUsage1 :IItemUsage
{
    public void Execute(ItemUsageArgs1 args)
    {
        //do you need
    }
    void IItemUsage.Execute(IItemUsageArgs args)
    {
        Execute(args as ItemUsageArgs1);
    }
}

public class ItemUsage2 : IItemUsage
{
    public void Execute(ItemUsageArgs2 args)
    {
        //do you need
    }
    void IItemUsage.Execute(IItemUsageArgs args)
    {
        Execute(args as ItemUsageArgs2);
    }
}
```